# convert opengl Window to std::size_t and back again works in Linux, but not OS X

Tags: c++, linux, macos, opengl, x11

I have successfully converted an OpenGL Window to an std::size_t variable and then converted it back to an OpenGL Window in Linux.  However, when I try to do the same thing in Mac OS X it isn't working.  Here's what I'm doing:

```
/* our window instance(This is an X Window System Window!) */
    Window window_;
.
.


.
.
std::size_t OSXGLWindow::getWindowHandle() {
    return window_;
}
.
.
```

Calling 'getWindowHandle()' just returns the Window as an std::size_t.

I pass this size_t window handle into the following function:

```
IInputManager* InputFactory::getInputMgr(std::size_t winHandle) {

    IInputManager* retObj = 0;
#ifdef _WIN32
    // todo: windows input implementation
#endif

#ifdef linux
    Window win = winHandle;
    retObj = new lwis::linuxos::LinuxInputManager(win);
#endif

#ifdef __APPLE__
    Window win = winHandle;
    retObj = new lwis::osx::OSXInputManager(win);
#endif

    return retObj;
}
```

The LinuxInputManager and OSXInputManager both call the following bit of code:

```
XSelectInput(display_, theWindow,
            KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask | KeymapStateMask) == BadWindow)
```

where 'theWindow' is the Window that was sent to the respective objects' constructor from the 'InputFactory::getInputMgr(..)' function.

The 'XSelectInput' is successful in the LinuxInputManager object for Linux, but not in the OSXInputManager for OS X.

Another important piece of information is that the Window is being passed between 2 static libraries, which is why it is converted to an std::size_t in the first place (to make it easy to pass between the libraries).

Anyone have any idea why this is?  Is there a better way to pass a handle between libraries?  Would a 'void*' be a better option?

Comment: What exactly is an "OpenGL Window"?

Comment: what is the underlying type of std::size_t in each environment?

Comment: @genpfault Sorry, i neglected to mention that 'Window' is an X Window System Window.

Comment: @geofftnz I was under the impression that std::size_t was always an unsigned int type.

Comment: could it be possible that it's 64bit in one and 32bit in the other? Or maybe it's 32bit in both, but what you're trying to push via it is 64bit?

Comment: @geofftnz interesting!  I didn't think so, but the mac is 64bit!  (checked with a sizeof(std::size_t)).  So it works in Linux but not Mac...which is weird (to me), I thought size_t was supposed to be big enough to fit the address of the Window (and if it's 64bit on a 64bit system I don't know why it wouldn't)..I'm such a newb :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

void* would be a fine option if you can't provide GL type information to getInputMgr. I assume you are trying to hide OpenGL definitions from the rest of your code?

Comment: sorry, I neglected to mention that 'Window' is in fact an X Window System Window.  I have edited my post accordingly.  What I was trying to accomplish was to hide the kind of window that was passed into the getInputMgr(..) method. I might want to send in something other than an X Window.

Answer (score 2):

Well, why do you expect some other, unrelated type `Window` to be convertible to `std::size_t` and back without any losses? I would guess that you wouldn't be surprised to see that `unsigned char` does not work in that role, would you? If so, why are you surprised to see `size_t` fail?

`size_t` is just some unsigned integer type, with certain size and range. If you are converting some unrelated type to `size_t`, the conversion result might fit into `size_t` or it might not fit into it, depending on the platform, on the properties of the source type etc. Apparently, this is exactly what happens in your case.

Comment: Hmm..I'm still relatively new to C++, but what I was trying to accomplish was to hide the _kind_ of window that was passed into the `getInputMgr(..)` method.  I might want to send in something other than an X Window.  The reason I used std::size_t was that I noticed another library using it in this manner, and I thought "I guess that's how it's done"..  @totowtwo below suggests that void* is perfectly acceptable, which accomplishes the goal, I just wasn't sure if it was the 'right' way to do it (and as I mentioned, I was following another libraries lead with the std::size_t).  Thanks!

Comment: Given that the `Window` type in X11 is opaque, and you don't know anything about it, you can't *portably* convert it to anything.  What works on one architecture may not work on another.  That being said `Window` has been defined as a 32 bit unsigned integer on every X11 implementation I've ever seen.  (Which does make it a bit of a mystery why `size_t` didn't work on Mac OS X.)

Comment: I discovered that my Mac is a 64bit architecture, which I suppose might explain it..std::size_t is 8bytes, and Window is only 4 bytes..maybe that causes problems when converting it.  That is a good point about the `Window`.  I think `void*` would give me the best portability (I'm just starting my Windows (XP) port now, so I guess time will tell) :)  Thanks again andrew

Comment: @Jarrett: If you really need to use an integer type to temporarily store a pointer value, the proper type is `uintptr_t`, not `size_t`. `uintptr_t` is not formally available in C++ (it is a C99 typedef), but many platforms provide it and you can always define it yourself.